# SQL Replication status

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, replication, publisher

I want to check the if the publisher's status when it stop for reinitialisation can I reinitialisation the publication using C# or SQL command

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: if i have the distributor and publisher how can i check whether the  publisher  in error or idle running